# How to intelligently apply DRY principles to tkinter OptionMenu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple tkinter app that works fine right now, but the code is not well written. My primary issue is that it seems that each OptionMenu needs to have its own tkvar and own testFunc in order to have the app behave the way I want it to. It doesn't seem like I can call additional variables in the command section, which is why it's hard for me to consolidate this code.

The purpose of the app is to allow the user to select the order of the animals and display that order right away. Hoping someone can illuminate the light for me to make this code more DRY and more intelligent.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_title("Choose Multiple Animals")
        self._frame = None

class AnimalPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.config(relief='sunken', borderwidth=2)
        self.pack(fill = "both", expand = False)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.animalList = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bear']
        self.choices = ['None', 'Animal1', 'Animal2', 'Animal3']
        self.tkvar1 = tk.StringVar(master)
        self.tkvar1.set('None')
        self.tkvar2 = tk.StringVar(master)
        self.tkvar2.set('None')
        self.tkvar3 = tk.StringVar(master)
        self.tkvar3.set('None')
        self.tkvar4 = tk.StringVar()

        self.textLabel1 = ttk.Label(self, text=self.animalList[0])
        self.textLabel1.grid(column=0, row = 5, sticky = (tk.W), padx=5, pady=5)
        self.popupMenu1 = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.tkvar1, *self.choices, command=self.testFunc1)
        self.popupMenu1.grid(column=1, row = 5, sticky = (tk.W, tk.E), padx=5, pady=5)
        self.textLabel2 = ttk.Label(self, text=self.animalList[1])
        self.textLabel2.grid(column=0, row = 6, sticky = (tk.W), padx=5, pady=5)
        self.popupMenu2 = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.tkvar2, *self.choices, command=self.testFunc2)
        self.popupMenu2.grid(column=1, row = 6, sticky = (tk.W, tk.E), padx=5, pady=5)
        self.textLabel3 = ttk.Label(self, text=self.animalList[2])
        self.textLabel3.grid(column=0, row = 7, sticky = (tk.W), padx=5, pady=5)
        self.popupMenu3 = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.tkvar3, *self.choices, command=self.testFunc3)
        self.popupMenu3.grid(column=1, row = 7, sticky = (tk.W, tk.E), padx=5, pady=5)
        self.chosenAnimals = {}

        self.textLabel4 = ttk.Label(self, text=self.tkvar4.get())
        self.textLabel4.grid(column=0, row = 8, sticky = (tk.W, tk.E), padx=5, pady=5)

    def testFunc1(self, value):
        self.chosenAnimals.update({value: self.animalList[0]})
        self.configure()

    def testFunc2(self, value):
        self.chosenAnimals.update({value: self.animalList[1]})
        self.configure()

    def testFunc3(self, value):
        self.chosenAnimals.update({value: self.animalList[2]})
        self.configure()

    def configure(self):
        self.printout = ["{} is the {}".format(k, v) for (k,v) in self.chosenAnimals.items()]
        self.tkvar4.set(self.printout)
        self.textLabel4.config(text = self.tkvar4.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    newFrame = AnimalPage(app, app)
    app.geometry("500x200")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of arrays or dictionaries:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.wm_title("Choose Multiple Animals")
        self._frame = None

class AnimalPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.config(relief='sunken', borderwidth=2)
        self.pack(fill = "both", expand = False)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.animalList = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bear']
        self.choices = ['None', 'Animal1', 'Animal2', 'Animal3']

        self.animal_vars = dict()
        self.text_labels = dict()
        self.popup_menus = dict()
        self.chosenAnimals = {}
        self.tkvar4 = tk.StringVar()

        for i, animal in enumerate(self.animalList):
            self.animal_vars[animal] = tk.StringVar(master)
            self.animal_vars[animal].set('None')
            self.text_labels[animal] = ttk.Label(self, text=animal)
            self.text_labels[animal].grid(column=0, row = 5 + i, sticky = (tk.W), padx=5, pady=5)
            self.popup_menus[animal] = ttk.OptionMenu(self, self.animal_vars[animal], *self.choices, command=lambda selected, my_animal=animal: self.testFunc(my_animal, selected))
            self.popup_menus[animal].grid(column=1, row = 5 + i, sticky = (tk.W, tk.E), padx=5, pady=5)

        self.textLabel4 = ttk.Label(self, text=self.tkvar4.get())
        self.textLabel4.grid(column=0, row = 8, sticky = (tk.W, tk.E), padx=5, pady=5)      

    def testFunc(self, animal, selection):
        self.chosenAnimals.update({animal: selection})
        self.configure()

    def configure(self):
        self.printout = ["{} is the {}".format(k, v) for (k,v) in self.chosenAnimals.items()]
        self.tkvar4.set(self.printout)
        self.textLabel4.config(text = self.tkvar4.get())
```

Since you're basically iterating through the `animalList` to create the `Label`s and `OptionMenu`s dynamically, you might as well use a `dict` or `list` to help you manage and iterate through the objects.

Once you have the `dict` or `list` set up, you can now assign/append the tk widgets you created into it and reference back easily.  In your example personally I prefer `dict` since each animal has a meaningful name to go with and easier to debug (looking for `self.text_labels['Cat']` would be easier than `self.text_labels[0]`)

Also, you can make use of `lambda` to bypass the limitation of `command=...` in tk widgets.  This way you pass the animal name right back to the function so you don't need to define it for each animal.

As an aside, ideally I would suggest you give your objects more meaningful names.  Stay away from terms like `textLabel4` or `tkvar4` so it's easier to understand the code.

## Important Note:

For the `lambda` to work in the loop you will need the iterated `animal` to be a default param instead of directly inside the `lambda`, a quick demo:

```
def func(v):
    print(v)

x = list(range(3))
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = lambda: func(i)

x[0]
# 2
```

You might expect `x[0]` will result in printing `0`, but in reality it will be `2`, and it will be the same result across `x[0:2]`.  The reason is that when the lambda is assigned, it's referencing the `i` object instead of its value of `[0, 1, 2]` in each iteration.  Therefore since the loop ended, `i = 2`, and your `x` funcs will always print `2`.

However, if you passed `i` as a default param in the lambda, the *value* will be passed:

```
x[i] = lambda y=i: func(y)

x[0]()
# 0
```

In conjunction with this fact, the reason why I used `lambda selected, my_animal=animal:...` is due to the `command=...` in the `OptionMenu` is always passing its `variable` (which in this case is the chosen Animal1, Animal2...) as the first param of the function.

Hope this clears things a bit.

Comment: Hi Idlehands , brilliant, thank you so much!!! I wish i could give you more than one upvote because of how well you addressed all of my questions and gave an answer that i (and others i hope) can use for building out own dropdown menus. I didnt know that the lambda would give you that ability. I knew a for loop was required but was not sure how to implement it, but combining it with dictionaries is a perfectly logical and beautiful way of defining it so that all the elements fit together in a DRY way. Thank you!

Comment: You're too welcome.  I just happened to go through a similar exercise not too long ago.  There are lots of tips and tricks for `tkinter` available if you dig into it.  Keep coding!

Comment: @LionelYu Sorry I dun goof'd on the `lambda`.  I've updated the `command=...` line and the `testFunc`.  It should now be identical to your existing functionalities.  Please update.

Comment: I noticed that earlier! I figured you didn't really bother with that section since it didn't focus as much on the nature of the question. But thank you, now your solution is perfect. I also realize the tkvar4 is not needed for this example, I think in my original code I was saving that for some other purpose. Your code basically has shrunken 60 lines of WET code into 10 lines of DRY code and allowed infinite dropdown tables + followup functions based the number of items in animalList. I feel really lucky you decided to answer my question today!

Comment: Yes technically `tkvar4` is not needed because `Label` doesn't take a var, so you can set the text directly to the `Label` in `self.configure()`.  If it wasn't me there will always be others willing to help out, I'm glad to be of help though!  Small note: I updated the `lambda` to clarify the `params` being passed as it's important to denote what is passed as a default param (besides the variable which you can see is passed as `selected`).  If you just put `animal` inside the `lambda` it won't work as the object reference will be the same across all three.  Test it out and see for yourself!

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. I'm not 100% sure on how lambda works but it seems that it is returning the value of the selection to be inputted into selected, and then the additional animal=animal argument you defined allows the animal to be added to the chosenAnimals dictionary rather than overwriting the other selections. I'm going to have to play around with this a bit more before I can understand it fully. Thanks again though :) truly.

Comment: I've appended some clarification notes in the answer regarding the `lambda` as I too once had trouble understanding that.  Hopefully it clear things up a bit for you and future readers.  No need to thank me again, just making sure I don't mislead people :)